# I want to read a text and store it in a variable through selenium in C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have this button on which a text is written. The text on the button is coming from a database and changes regularly. I want to save this text in a variable for further processing. The html tag is given below

`<button type="button" id="hvac1_sequence" class="btn btn-warning" style="width:60px;">Lag</button>`

I want to save "Lag" in the variable through Selenium Webdriver using C#. I have tried these following codes but none of them worked as I experienced error.

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("hvac1_sequence")).Text
var element = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("btn btn-warning")).Text
var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@id='hvac1_sequence']")).Text
```

I have also tried to save them in IWebElement rather than var. Still same error. Can anyone help me?

Edit 1 : Error is Something like Selenium cannot find the Id or Selenium cannot find the Xpath given

Edit 2 : Exact Error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll. Additional information: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"hvac1_sequence"}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I edited the question you can see the error

Comment: Post the exact error message, not *something like*. Check if the button is in `<iframe>` tag and switch to it. If not try adding some [wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)

Comment: Posted the exact error

Comment: maybe if you show us the DOM source we can spot why the element is not found using the selectors you used

Comment: What is a DOM Source?

Comment: We indicate that questions are solved here on SO by accepting an answer (yes, even your own, but there's an enforced time delay before you're allowed to do so)

Comment: I rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate here to add SOLVED to the title or add the solution to the question. If an answer below solved the problem, you can indicate it's been solved by accepting the answer (checking the mark below the score). If you've solved the problem on your own and want to share the solution, write an answer in the space below that is designed for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for information regarding how to do so. Also, the [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52639343/revisions) tracks edits.

Answer (score 0):

The error was occuring because the frame was not selected. I used the following method to select the frame

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("temporary");
```

Where the temporary is the id of iframe

Comment: If anyone else comes across this, make sure you switch back to default context once you are done interacting with the iFrame.